# Nagios/Gammu, nagios user can't send sms

Tags: nagios, sms

I have a Nagios, and Gammu installed.

When I use gammu as root, like the following :

```
/usr/bin/gammu identify (or else)
```

It works, but when I do it as nagios user, i got this answer :

```
Can't open specified file. Read only?
```

I even put nagios in the root group, I used visudo with :

```
nagios ALL=(ALL)  ALL
```

But no ... I can't find any solution with google.
So if someone got an idea, it would be great !

I don't have any error in logs...

This was solved using this [link](http://users.telenet.be/mydotcom/howto/nagios/pluginsudo.html).

So I added :

```
ALL=(root) NOPASSWD: /usr/sbin/smartctl
```

And in the plugin :

```
my $smart_command = '/usr/bin/sudo /usr/sbin/smartctl'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to put your nagios user in the `dialout` group or whatever group it is that has access to the serial ports connected to the GSM modem.

find out with something like this:

```
ls -l /dev/ttyS2
crw-rw---- 1 root dialout 4, 66 May 17 12:19 /dev/ttyS2
```

(but replace `ttyS2` with the correct device).

Using `sudo` is the wrong approach for a program like `gammu` that is called by a daemon process.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but already done. My group is 'uucp', and nagios belong to it. And I haven't any dialout group, I can't explain why ? Thank you @SvW  (btw why I got a -1 ?)

Comment: I also tried chmod 4777 and 2777 but still have a problem. And with 4777, when i launch my /usr/bin/gammu, I have the same problem : Can't open specified file, even if I'm loggin as root ... Need help :)

Comment: Have a look at http://users.telenet.be/mydotcom/howto/nagios/pluginsudo.html. Here's the solution ;) (Can't answer my own post =[ )